# set onclick() attribute for un ordered list

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to web development

I need to know how to set an onclick() attribute for the elements in an unordered list

here is my code :

```
<ul id = "headlist">
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>Gallery</li>
      <li>Downloads</li>
</ul>
```

How to set onclick attribute for the elements and based on the items in the list , the click should take the user to a particular webpage

Comment: you're missing `<li>` tags! Before jumping into the JS oven, make sure you baked HTML very well.

Comment: ...and why not just use a link?

Comment: Your html isn't valid html. In addition, tell us what you've researched and tried, there's tons of info on click handlers in html out there already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got the HTML a bit wrong, how about something like this:

```
<ul id = "headlist">
      <li><a href="link-to-the-page">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="link-to-the-page">Gallery</a></li>
      <li><a href="link-to-the-page">HomeDownloads/a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

In lists, the actual list items need to be inside `<li>` tags like:

```
<ul id = "headlist">
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>Gallery</li>
      <li>Downloads</li>
</ul>
```

If you want the list items to open another page, the easiest way is a link:

```
<li><a href="http://google.com">Link Here</a></li>
```

But, if you want to do it with JS, here is one option:

```
<li onclick="window.location='http://google.com'">Link Here</li>
```

or, if you want to shorten it:

```
<script>
    function link(src){
    window.location=src;
    }
</script>

<li onclick="link('http://google.com')">Link Here</li>
```